# how to retrieve a custom tag from an mp3 file using eyeD3 (or any other command line tool...)?

Tags: linux, tags, mp3, playlist

I want to automaticly create a christmas-playlist from my music files stored on my linux synology NAS.

Therefore, I'd like to read the tag-info with a command line tool for all my music in all of the folders to create the playlist.

I have tagged some mp3 files with a tag "XMAS" (set the value of XMAS = 1) and if it exists in an mp3 file, then the song is a christmas song and it should go to my playlist.

I found a tool here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/226773/how-to-read-mp3-tags-in-shell

but I cannot figure out, how to read my XMAS tag.

The tool only shows "standard" tags, like artist, title, ... but I need to check for a present XMAS-tag in my files to grep it.

`eyeD3 -v test.mp3` (file has id3v2.3 tags) does not show an existing XMAS-tag.

Can anybody tell, if its possible with eyeD3 or name a tool which can read out mp3 info? (I tried `mp3info` too, but it only recognizes old id3-tag-version, but my tags are stored mostly on newer tag version)

Thank you!

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related site askubuntu.com. Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Good luck.

Comment: You are correct, sorry. Anyway, I found a tool, which will do exactly what I was searching for: `id3info` [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/id3info.1.html) Need to be installed via the `libid3-tools`